# MySQL безопасность скрипта PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, get, защита

Из мобильного приложения передаётся get запрос на скрипт PHP такого вида:

```
script.php?mycode=123&os_type=ios
```

В скрипте я написал жалкое подобие защиты:

```
$os = $_GET["os_type"];
if ($os!=='Android' && $os!=='iOS')
{echo 'ERROR!'; Exit();}

$item = $_GET["mycode"];
$escaped_item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);

$escaped_item = strip_tags($escaped_item);

    $escaped_item = htmlspecialchars($escaped_item);

    $escaped_item = stripslashes($escaped_item);

    $escaped_item = addslashes($escaped_item);  
    $escaped_item=trim($escaped_item);

    $code=$escaped_item;
```

Результат выводится путем поиска в БД данного кода и возвращается в виде echo.
Вопрос 1: В этом же скрипте идет подключение к БД с указанием имени и пароля пользователя БД - Безопасно ли это? И на сколько?
Вопрос 2: На сколько моя защита эффективна если речь идет о простенькой инди игре для детей и вся БД лишь набор Промо-кодов на отключение рекламы и записи в нее информации о использовании конкретного кода, дате активации кода и платформы с которой прошла активация. Web интерфейса для доступа к скрипту нет. Просто 1 файл на хостинге.

Comment: Попробуйте натравить на этот URL замечательную тулзу sqlmap. Очевидные дыры она сама найдет.

Comment: Что вы перемудрили, если вы собрались подставлять пришедшую переменную в текст sql запроса - то mysql_real_escape_string хватит за глаза, после него mysql гарантированно воспримет вашу переменную именно как текст. С другой стороны, если взять за правило не писать никаких значений переменных непосредственно в sql запросе, а привязывать их параметры или пердавать при execute, то их и эскейпить не надо и они вам ничего не сделают. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Ну и заодно, расширение `mysql_` давным-давно протухло. Не стоит писать нового кода с его использованием

Answer (score 1):

> В этом же скрипте идет подключение к БД с указанием имени и пароля пользователя БД - Безопасно ли это?

Этот вариант используется в 100% пхп скриптов. Без подключения невозможно сделать запрос, а без имени и пароля не будет подключения.

> Вопрос 2: На сколько моя защита эффективна

Без обид, но она, скорее, смехотворна. Это что-то вророде такого: выходя на улицу, надеть на себя шубу (защита от холода), намазать щубу кремом от загара (защита от солнечного ожога), снять шубу (защита от теплового удара), надеть презерватив (защита от ЗПП) и обуться (никакой защиты, но просто до кучи).

Как написали выше в комментариях, надо испльзовать [PDО](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo) и передавать переменные в запрос через плейсхолдер. А все эти защитные препарации выкинуть на помойку.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where code=?");
$stmt->execute([$_GET["mycode"]]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

И в $data будет массив данных, которые вернула БД.

Если данные в БД попадают от пользователей, или должны выводиться в виде значений полей формы, то перед выводом обработать через htmlspecialchars().